# How to create error message if column contains non-numeric field - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to produce an error message if the values of the table are non-numeric. I am not getting any error messages but the code isn't accomplishing the task. Any help? Code below:

```
Sub Refresh()
'
' Warning Code to check if all values are numeric
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim bisnumberic As Boolean

bIsNumeric = True

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case sh.Name
        Case "AltA", "AltB", "AltC1", "AltC2"
            Dim lRow As Long
            lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 3 To lRow
                If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                    bisnumber = False
                End If
            Next i
    End Select
Next sh

    If bIsNumeric = False Then
            'There are non-numeric values in your range
            MsgBox "There are non-numeric values in your range. Go check-            
yourself and try again."
        Else
 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Code to summarize data           Sheets("AlternativeSummary").Select
        Range("B5").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
        MsgBox "Complete"
        'All values in your range are numeric

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Dim bisnumberic As Boolean is also problematic. Better use Option Explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` should have a clearly defined parent worksheet. Remember that you are cycling through a series of worksheets. Same with `If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then`.

```
Sub Refresh()
    '
    ' Warning Code to check if all values are numeric
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, bIsNumeric As Boolean, lRow As Long, errng as range

    bIsNumeric = True

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sh.Name
            Case "AltA", "AltB", "AltC1", "AltC2"
                lRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                For i = 3 To lRow
                    If Not IsNumeric(sh.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                        bIsNumeric = False
                        set errng  = sh.Cells(i, 1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
        End Select
        If Not bIsNumeric Then Exit For
    Next sh

    If Not bIsNumeric Then
        'There are non-numeric values in your range
        MsgBox "There are non-numeric values in your range. Go check yourself and try again." _
               & chr(10) & errng.address(0, 0, external:=true)
    Else
        '---------------------------------------------------
        ' Code to summarize data
        With Sheets("AlternativeSummary")
            .Activate
            .Range("B5").Select
            .PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
            MsgBox "Complete"
            'All values in your range are numeric
        end with
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in your if statement:

```
            If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                bisnumber = False
            End If
```

You are changing the `bisnumber` variable.

Later on, you actually check the `bIsNumeric` variable to see if something is or is not a number. You would need to change:

```
            If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                bisnumber = False
            End If
```

to:

```
            If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                bIsNumeric = False
            End If
```

Good code writing - and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I appreciate all the help! It is still not working.. I have changed the code to now read bisnumeric throughout. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be changing the sheet name by the Case definition. That is, when I put a non-numeric number into tab "AltB" I still get the code for if bIsNumeric = True, ie. the pivot table refreshes.

My latest code in next comment.

Comment: Use of case statement is not required at all. The `For Each sh` part takes care of looping through the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Refresh()
'
' Warning Code to check if all values are numeric
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim bIsNumeric As Boolean

bIsNumeric = True

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lRow + 1
        If Not IsNumeric(sh.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            bIsNumeric = False
        End If
    Next i
Next sh

If bIsNumeric = False Then 'There are non-numeric values in your range
    MsgBox "There are non-numeric values in your range. Go check-yourself and try again."
Else
 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Code to summarize data           Sheets("AlternativeSummary").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
MsgBox "Complete"
'All values in your range are numeric

End If


End Sub
```

This will loop through all the sheets and check for non-numeric fields.

Comment: Corrected now! Thanks for your input.

Comment: Use of case statement is not required at all. The `For Each sh` part takes care of looping through the sheets.